# How to add thymeleaf attribute in html using jquery

Tags: jquery, thymeleaf

**How to add thymeleaf attribute in html using jquery**
should i use attr() or data()

```
$("#previous").attr("control", "-6");
```

or

```
$("#previous").data("control", "-6");
```

in my app i m using thymeleaf,
example th:href="@{updateAdmin.html?accountId={id}"

how will i add above attribute and value in html

**jquery code**

```
$(".display").on('click', '.row-edit', function(){ 
        alert("Editing a row");
        $(this).removeClass("row-edit").addClass("row-editremove");   
        $(this).closest('tr').after(new_editrow);
        $(".src-remove.select-drp").select2({minimumResultsForSearch: -1,});
        $('.add-module,.add-usermd').hide();
        $('.accounts-rgt').show();
        $('.accountdt,.createrole,.createaccuser,.parentaccountdt').remove();$('.remove-user').removeClass("remove-user").addClass("add-user");$('.parrow-remove').removeClass("parrow-remove").addClass("parrow-add");$('.row-remove').removeClass("row-remove").addClass("row-add");$('.remove-row').removeClass("remove-row").addClass("add-row");
      });

    $(".display").on('click', '.row-editremove', function(){ 
        $(this).removeClass("row-editremove").addClass("row-edit");   
        $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').remove();
      });
```

**html code**

```
<li><a th:href="@{updateAdmin.html?accountId={id}(id=${aal.accountId})}"><i class="spt-icon edit row-edit"></i><i class="spt-icon inlineedit"></i></a></li>
```

Comment: `$("#previous").attr("data-control", "-6");`?

Comment: @Tushar: i have th:href="@{updateAdmin.html?accountId={id}" ,how would i use jquery to add this in html

Comment: Whats thymeleaf? Do you mean you want to add a "data-thymeleaf" attribute?

Comment: As in $('#previous').attr('data-thymeleaf', 'value');

Comment: Try giving my suggestion a go and let me know @abcC

Comment: @AdamJeffers: thymeleaf is view for spring

Comment: @ChrisBeckett: I gave a try but still it's not working

Comment: @abcC Does it give you any errors?

Comment: @ChrisBeckett:no error, it giving correct value.

Comment: it is giving correct value but functionality is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the thymeleaf attribute from HTML jQuery. But it wont render. I hope you are aware of the fact that thymeleaf is a server side technology while jquery is a client.

To add the attribute. you can use.

```
$('a').attr('th:href', '@{updateAdmin.html?accountId={id}(id=${aal.accountId})}');
```

But still again it wont render due to the fact i mentioned above. Rethink your design and wht you want to do.